# Trouble with a specific glew linker reference (C++ Codeblocks MinGW OpenGL and SDL)

Tags: c++, opengl, windows-10, codeblocks, wsdl-2.0

I'm practicing graphics tutorials on youtube with a Windows 10 machine and I'm trying to write a simple program to render a sprite onscreen using a vertex buffer object but I'm having some issues.

I've gotten previous projects using glew to work. I've loaded a window and drawn a triangle on it, but when I try to set up and delete buffers, I get undefined references for these specific functions: glDeleteBuffers, glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData, etc.

I'm currently compiling with the following linker options:

> -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_Image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_net -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglew32 -lglew32s -lglew32mx

and I feel like all of my search directories are also correct. I have #define GLEW_STATIC in the first class that I load, but I'm not sure how glew is only half working. Is there a specific file or setup step I'm missing? Why do things like glClearDepth and glClear work if the others don't?

This is the tutorial I've been following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_OctRsu754

Comment: Try following: Remove these flags `-lglew32 -lglew32s -lglew32mx` and add the GLEW source as your own file to the project. Don't worry, it's just a single file. You may need to add `#define GLEW_STATIC` as first line of that file, I'm not sure if it's necessary.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat When you say add just one file, do you mean glew.h or glew.c or something else? I tried adding just glew.c to the project but then it gave me a bunch of warnings for duplicate declarations, but if I add both glew.c and glew.h to the project, I still get the same exact errors. I did remove the flags from the linker as well.

Comment: I've meant `glew.c`. Have you inserted `#define GLEW_STATIC` into `glew.c`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have here's my source code so far on pastebin.com/xMKFdzQC. I have #define GLEW_STATIC in glew.c which is in the folder and included in the project but then it gives me 2963 duplicate declaration warnings and still the original 10 errors.

Comment: You're missing `#define GLEW_STATIC` inside of `Sprite.h`. You need to add that before every inclusion of `glew.h`.

Comment: Oh wow thanks so much! It's working and I have a white sprite rectangle drawn now. Why is it that I have to have #define GLEW_STATIC before the other things, and what does it do?

Comment: If you don't have GLEW_STATIC, then you need to put a special `.dll` file next to your executable (I think it is`glew32.dll`). This is called *dynamic linking*. Another option is *static linking*. You need to define that macro, and then you don't need that `.dll`, but you need to *statically link* GLEW. There are 2 ways to do it. One is to add GLEW source to your project as if it was your code (you just did it). Second way is to add `-static` flag for the linker (you also would need to readd those 3 `-l_` flags). If you have any more questions, you should google them or look into GLEW manual.